# Save HBITMAP to *.bmp file using only Win32

Tags: c, windows, winapi, bitmapimage, hbitmap

I have a HBITMAP in my pure Win32 project (no external libraries are used). Can I export it to a *.bmp file using only Winapi and/or CRT functions so I don't have to add dependencies to the project?

Comment: How on earth is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644709/c-hbitmap-bitmap-into-bmp-file supposed to be a duplicate of this question, given the fact it was posed and answered 4 days before it? How physically is that possible?

Comment: @enhzflep They're duplicates of each other's. Whichever gets more qualified answers first, the other shall be closed. This has nothing to do with the date and time that questions were asked.

Comment: @user814412 - I don't know what your first language is and what the meaning of the equivalent word is. In English, one is a duplicate of the other. The duplicate _ALWAYS_ comes second. A similar word is copy. The first instance of something is the original, the next is the copy or duplicate. This has _everything_ to do with time and date.

Comment: @enhzflep I think that the words such as _duplicate_ and _triplicate_ comes from the word _replicate,_ which means _to copy something._ You're right on that _du_ prefix _ALWAYS_ means _2,_ thus a _duplicate_ needs an original instance to be defined. I think the problem here is at SO's wording of its rule. I believe they meant _replicate_ or _replica_ and not _duplicate_ since we have seen many examples of the latter among two instances being closed due to this. And this is yet another example. Please don't trouble yourself.

Comment: I meant _former_ but wrote _latter_ by mistake.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no API to save into file directly because, generally, having a bitmap handle does not mean you have direct access to bitmap data. Your solution is to copy bitmap into another bitmap with data access (DIB) and then using it data to write into file.

You typically either create another bitmap using `CreateDIBSection`, or you get bitmap data with `GetDIBits`.

`CreateFile`, `WriteFile` writes data into file.

You write: `BITMAPFILEHEADER`, then `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, then palette (which you typically don't have when bits/pixel is over 8), then data itself.

See also:

- [C++: Hbitmap/BITMAP into .bmp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644709/c-hbitmap-bitmap-into-bmp-file) ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644907/868014))
- [Saving .bmp file using hBitmap = CreateDIBSection() in C Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606906/saving-bmp-file-using-hbitmap-createdibsection-in-c-win32)
- [Storing an Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN

### The Code

This is the code from the MSDN article (**Note** that you need to define the `errhandler()` function):

```
PBITMAPINFO CreateBitmapInfoStruct(HWND hwnd, HBITMAP hBmp)
{ 
    BITMAP bmp; 
    PBITMAPINFO pbmi; 
    WORD    cClrBits; 

    // Retrieve the bitmap color format, width, and height.  
    if (!GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), (LPSTR)&bmp)) 
        errhandler("GetObject", hwnd); 

    // Convert the color format to a count of bits.  
    cClrBits = (WORD)(bmp.bmPlanes * bmp.bmBitsPixel); 
    if (cClrBits == 1) 
        cClrBits = 1; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 4) 
        cClrBits = 4; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 8) 
        cClrBits = 8; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 16) 
        cClrBits = 16; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 24) 
        cClrBits = 24; 
    else cClrBits = 32; 

    // Allocate memory for the BITMAPINFO structure. (This structure  
    // contains a BITMAPINFOHEADER structure and an array of RGBQUAD  
    // data structures.)  

    if (cClrBits < 24) 
        pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO) LocalAlloc(LPTR, 
        sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 
        sizeof(RGBQUAD) * (1<< cClrBits)); 

    // There is no RGBQUAD array for these formats: 24-bit-per-pixel or 32-bit-per-pixel 

    else 
        pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO) LocalAlloc(LPTR, 
        sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)); 

    // Initialize the fields in the BITMAPINFO structure.  

    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = bmp.bmWidth; 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = bmp.bmHeight; 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = bmp.bmPlanes; 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = bmp.bmBitsPixel; 
    if (cClrBits < 24) 
        pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = (1<<cClrBits); 

    // If the bitmap is not compressed, set the BI_RGB flag.  
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB; 

    // Compute the number of bytes in the array of color  
    // indices and store the result in biSizeImage.  
    // The width must be DWORD aligned unless the bitmap is RLE 
    // compressed. 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth * cClrBits +31) & ~31) /8
        * pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight; 
    // Set biClrImportant to 0, indicating that all of the  
    // device colors are important.  
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0; 
    return pbmi; 
} 

void CreateBMPFile(HWND hwnd, LPTSTR pszFile, PBITMAPINFO pbi, 
                   HBITMAP hBMP, HDC hDC) 
{ 
    HANDLE hf;                 // file handle  
    BITMAPFILEHEADER hdr;       // bitmap file-header  
    PBITMAPINFOHEADER pbih;     // bitmap info-header  
    LPBYTE lpBits;              // memory pointer  
    DWORD dwTotal;              // total count of bytes  
    DWORD cb;                   // incremental count of bytes  
    BYTE *hp;                   // byte pointer  
    DWORD dwTmp; 

    pbih = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER) pbi; 
    lpBits = (LPBYTE) GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, pbih->biSizeImage);

    if (!lpBits) 
        errhandler("GlobalAlloc", hwnd); 

    // Retrieve the color table (RGBQUAD array) and the bits  
    // (array of palette indices) from the DIB.  
    if (!GetDIBits(hDC, hBMP, 0, (WORD) pbih->biHeight, lpBits, pbi, 
        DIB_RGB_COLORS)) 
    {
        errhandler("GetDIBits", hwnd); 
    }

    // Create the .BMP file.  
    hf = CreateFile(pszFile, 
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
        (DWORD) 0, 
        NULL, 
        CREATE_ALWAYS, 
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
        (HANDLE) NULL); 
    if (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        errhandler("CreateFile", hwnd); 
    hdr.bfType = 0x4d42;        // 0x42 = "B" 0x4d = "M"  
    // Compute the size of the entire file.  
    hdr.bfSize = (DWORD) (sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + 
        pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed 
        * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + pbih->biSizeImage); 
    hdr.bfReserved1 = 0; 
    hdr.bfReserved2 = 0; 

    // Compute the offset to the array of color indices.  
    hdr.bfOffBits = (DWORD) sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + 
        pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed 
        * sizeof (RGBQUAD); 

    // Copy the BITMAPFILEHEADER into the .BMP file.  
    if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPVOID) &hdr, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 
        (LPDWORD) &dwTmp,  NULL)) 
    {
        errhandler("WriteFile", hwnd); 
    }

    // Copy the BITMAPINFOHEADER and RGBQUAD array into the file.  
    if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPVOID) pbih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) 
        + pbih->biClrUsed * sizeof (RGBQUAD), 
        (LPDWORD) &dwTmp, ( NULL)))
        errhandler("WriteFile", hwnd); 

    // Copy the array of color indices into the .BMP file.  
    dwTotal = cb = pbih->biSizeImage; 
    hp = lpBits; 
    if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPSTR) hp, (int) cb, (LPDWORD) &dwTmp,NULL)) 
        errhandler("WriteFile", hwnd); 

    // Close the .BMP file.  
    if (!CloseHandle(hf)) 
        errhandler("CloseHandle", hwnd); 

    // Free memory.  
    GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)lpBits);
}
```

Comment: Actually, you *can* save an `HBITMAP` without having to manually convert it. It takes a bit of code to create a stream on a file, create an encoder, and then dumping frames into it. However, the heavy-lifting is done in [IWICImagingFactory::CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690287.aspx) and the [IWICBitmapEncoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690110.aspx), so you don't have to fiddle with bitmap headers.

Answer (score 10):

One function code for `HBITMAP` to `*.bmp` file.

```
BOOL SaveHBITMAPToFile(HBITMAP hBitmap, LPCTSTR lpszFileName)
{
    HDC hDC;
    int iBits;
    WORD wBitCount;
    DWORD dwPaletteSize = 0, dwBmBitsSize = 0, dwDIBSize = 0, dwWritten = 0;
    BITMAP Bitmap0;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfHdr;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    LPBITMAPINFOHEADER lpbi;
    HANDLE fh, hDib, hPal, hOldPal2 = NULL;
    hDC = CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
    iBits = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, BITSPIXEL) * GetDeviceCaps(hDC, PLANES);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
    if (iBits <= 1)
        wBitCount = 1;
    else if (iBits <= 4)
        wBitCount = 4;
    else if (iBits <= 8)
        wBitCount = 8;
    else
        wBitCount = 24;
    GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(Bitmap0), (LPSTR)&Bitmap0);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = Bitmap0.bmWidth;
    bi.biHeight = -Bitmap0.bmHeight;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = wBitCount;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 256;
    dwBmBitsSize = ((Bitmap0.bmWidth * wBitCount + 31) & ~31) / 8
        * Bitmap0.bmHeight;
    hDib = GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwBmBitsSize + dwPaletteSize + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    lpbi = (LPBITMAPINFOHEADER)GlobalLock(hDib);
    *lpbi = bi;

    hPal = GetStockObject(DEFAULT_PALETTE);
    if (hPal)
    {
        hDC = GetDC(NULL);
        hOldPal2 = SelectPalette(hDC, (HPALETTE)hPal, FALSE);
        RealizePalette(hDC);
    }


    GetDIBits(hDC, hBitmap, 0, (UINT)Bitmap0.bmHeight, (LPSTR)lpbi + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)
        + dwPaletteSize, (BITMAPINFO *)lpbi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    if (hOldPal2)
    {
        SelectPalette(hDC, (HPALETTE)hOldPal2, TRUE);
        RealizePalette(hDC);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
    }

    fh = CreateFile(lpszFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);

    if (fh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return FALSE;

    bmfHdr.bfType = 0x4D42; // "BM"
    dwDIBSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + dwPaletteSize + dwBmBitsSize;
    bmfHdr.bfSize = dwDIBSize;
    bmfHdr.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmfHdr.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bmfHdr.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + dwPaletteSize;

    WriteFile(fh, (LPSTR)&bmfHdr, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwWritten, NULL);

    WriteFile(fh, (LPSTR)lpbi, dwDIBSize, &dwWritten, NULL);
    GlobalUnlock(hDib);
    GlobalFree(hDib);
    CloseHandle(fh);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I find this very helpful, but here's a question: once `HBITMAP` has been written to a file, I can't reuse it in a resource file (`.rc` / `.o`) because its image header is apparently not compatible. I improvised a way, opening the file in Paint and then saving it replaces image header part with Paint's default one and that way it's reusable. To emulate this effect (because I need it to be feasible in batching) I tried replicating default image header of Paint's but so far I've been unable to do so. Can you take a look at this matter please?

Comment: If you could just add the default image header of Paint's to this code, it'll be wonderful. I mean, how can we use the same file/image header settings that Paint applies to `.bmp` files by default? I'm an amateur and that's why I can't do it by myself. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Yet another minimalistic option is to use OLE's [`IPicture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ocidl/nn-ocidl-ipicture). It's always been around, still a part of Win32 API:

```
#define _S(exp) (([](HRESULT hr) { if (FAILED(hr)) _com_raise_error(hr); return hr; })(exp));

PICTDESC pictdesc = {};
pictdesc.cbSizeofstruct = sizeof(pictdesc);
pictdesc.picType = PICTYPE_BITMAP;
pictdesc.bmp.hbitmap = hBitmap;

CComPtr<IPicture> picture;
_S( OleCreatePictureIndirect(&pictdesc, __uuidof(IPicture), FALSE, (LPVOID*)&picture) );

// Save to a stream

CComPtr<IStream> stream;
_S( CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &stream) );
LONG cbSize = 0;
_S( picture->SaveAsFile(stream, TRUE, &cbSize) );

// Or save to a file

CComPtr<IPictureDisp> disp;
_S( picture->QueryInterface(&disp) );
_S( OleSavePictureFile(disp, CComBSTR("C:\\Temp\\File.bmp")) );
```

Comment: The `hBitmap` in `pictdesc.bmp.hbitmap = hBitmap;` seems undeclared. Do you have any idea how to resolve?

Comment: @JAMESBRYANB.Juventud, `hBitmap` is what you already have, as per OP's question, of `HBITMAP` type. This is a Win32 handle to the bitmap which content you want to save to a file.

Comment: It's my fault. I haven't read fully OP's question. All he wants is exporting. So basically, he has a `bitmap` already. Thanks!

Comment: Note you could just use SHCreateStreamOnFile + SaveAsFile, you don't need an intermediary stream on HGlobal nor the OleSavePictureFile call.

Answer (score 7):

i'll leave this self contained proof of concept here since I'll probably need to look it up later since it's not obvious. It takes a screenshot of the desktop window and saves it into bitmap.bmp:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* forward declarations */
PBITMAPINFO CreateBitmapInfoStruct(HBITMAP);
void CreateBMPFile(LPTSTR pszFile, HBITMAP hBMP); 
int main(int argc, char **argv);

PBITMAPINFO CreateBitmapInfoStruct(HBITMAP hBmp)
{ 
    BITMAP bmp; 
    PBITMAPINFO pbmi; 
    WORD    cClrBits; 

    // Retrieve the bitmap color format, width, and height.  
    assert(GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), (LPSTR)&bmp)); 

    // Convert the color format to a count of bits.  
    cClrBits = (WORD)(bmp.bmPlanes * bmp.bmBitsPixel); 
    if (cClrBits == 1) 
        cClrBits = 1; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 4) 
        cClrBits = 4; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 8) 
        cClrBits = 8; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 16) 
        cClrBits = 16; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 24) 
        cClrBits = 24; 
    else cClrBits = 32; 

    // Allocate memory for the BITMAPINFO structure. (This structure  
    // contains a BITMAPINFOHEADER structure and an array of RGBQUAD  
    // data structures.)  

     if (cClrBits < 24) 
         pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO) LocalAlloc(LPTR, 
                    sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 
                    sizeof(RGBQUAD) * (1<< cClrBits)); 

     // There is no RGBQUAD array for these formats: 24-bit-per-pixel or 32-bit-per-pixel 

     else 
         pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO) LocalAlloc(LPTR, 
                    sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)); 

    // Initialize the fields in the BITMAPINFO structure.  

    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = bmp.bmWidth; 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = bmp.bmHeight; 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = bmp.bmPlanes; 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = bmp.bmBitsPixel; 
    if (cClrBits < 24) 
        pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = (1<<cClrBits); 

    // If the bitmap is not compressed, set the BI_RGB flag.  
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB; 

    // Compute the number of bytes in the array of color  
    // indices and store the result in biSizeImage.  
    // The width must be DWORD aligned unless the bitmap is RLE 
    // compressed. 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth * cClrBits +31) & ~31) /8
                                  * pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight; 
    // Set biClrImportant to 0, indicating that all of the  
    // device colors are important.  
     pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0; 
     return pbmi; 
 } 

void CreateBMPFile(LPTSTR pszFile, HBITMAP hBMP) 
 { 
     HANDLE hf;                 // file handle  
    BITMAPFILEHEADER hdr;       // bitmap file-header  
    PBITMAPINFOHEADER pbih;     // bitmap info-header  
    LPBYTE lpBits;              // memory pointer  
    DWORD dwTotal;              // total count of bytes  
    DWORD cb;                   // incremental count of bytes  
    BYTE *hp;                   // byte pointer  
    DWORD dwTmp;     
    PBITMAPINFO pbi;
    HDC hDC;

    hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow()));
    SelectObject(hDC, hBMP);

    pbi = CreateBitmapInfoStruct(hBMP);

    pbih = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER) pbi; 
    lpBits = (LPBYTE) GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, pbih->biSizeImage);

    assert(lpBits) ;

    // Retrieve the color table (RGBQUAD array) and the bits  
    // (array of palette indices) from the DIB.  
    assert(GetDIBits(hDC, hBMP, 0, (WORD) pbih->biHeight, lpBits, pbi, 
        DIB_RGB_COLORS));

    // Create the .BMP file.  
    hf = CreateFile(pszFile, 
                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                   (DWORD) 0, 
                    NULL, 
                   CREATE_ALWAYS, 
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
                   (HANDLE) NULL); 
    assert(hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ;

    hdr.bfType = 0x4d42;        // 0x42 = "B" 0x4d = "M"  
    // Compute the size of the entire file.  
    hdr.bfSize = (DWORD) (sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + 
                 pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed 
                 * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + pbih->biSizeImage); 
    hdr.bfReserved1 = 0; 
    hdr.bfReserved2 = 0; 

    // Compute the offset to the array of color indices.  
    hdr.bfOffBits = (DWORD) sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + 
                    pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed 
                    * sizeof (RGBQUAD); 

    // Copy the BITMAPFILEHEADER into the .BMP file.  
    assert(WriteFile(hf, (LPVOID) &hdr, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 
        (LPDWORD) &dwTmp,  NULL)); 

    // Copy the BITMAPINFOHEADER and RGBQUAD array into the file.  
    assert(WriteFile(hf, (LPVOID) pbih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) 
                  + pbih->biClrUsed * sizeof (RGBQUAD), 
                  (LPDWORD) &dwTmp, ( NULL)));

    // Copy the array of color indices into the .BMP file.  
    dwTotal = cb = pbih->biSizeImage; 
    hp = lpBits; 
    assert(WriteFile(hf, (LPSTR) hp, (int) cb, (LPDWORD) &dwTmp,NULL)); 

    // Close the .BMP file.  
     assert(CloseHandle(hf)); 

    // Free memory.  
    GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)lpBits);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hdc[2];
    HBITMAP hbitmap;
    RECT rect;

    hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
    hdc[0] = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
    hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc[0], rect.right, rect.bottom); 
    hdc[1] = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc[0]);
    SelectObject(hdc[1], hbitmap);    

    BitBlt (    
        hdc[1],
        0,
        0,
        rect.right,
        rect.bottom,
        hdc[0],
        0,
        0,
        SRCCOPY
    );

    CreateBMPFile("bitmap.bmp", hbitmap);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitry, for the nice chunk of code. You made my day. Cheers!

Comment: To save bmp file on D drive use  CreateBMPFile("D:\\bitmap.bmp", hbitmap);

Comment: @Dmitry @Martin There is an error that says: `uninitialized local variable 'bmp' used`. The code already declared `BITMAP bmp`. Why?

Comment: @JAMESBRYANB.Juventud my guess is because you're compiling it as c++ compiler or a different compiler. I can't tell without you saying which line the warning is, but it is indeed initialized using GetObject and checked whether GetObject succeeded or not.

Comment: @Dmitry I'm using MSVS C++ compiler to compile this code.

Comment: @JAMESBRYANB.Juventud perhaps some newer warning about using a variable without using assignment operator to give it value first. Since GetObject assigns the value rather than you directly, it might expect you to set it to 0 or INVALID_HANDLE before using it. The code was only tested for Microsoft MSVC under C compile mode in settings in a .c file so it might be a C++ only warning since the compiler doesn't know for sure whether GetObject assigns the value or not, try assigning it to 0 or INVALID_HANDLE or NULL before it is used anywhere and see if it still complains.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is possible, using the [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx) (WIC). WIC offers built-in encoders, so that you don't have to manually write out bitmap headers and data. It also allows you to choose a different encoder (e.g. PNG), by changing as little as one line of code.

The process is fairly straight forward. It consists of the following steps:

1. Retrieve properties from the source `HBITMAP` using [`GetObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904.aspx) (dimensions, bit depth).
2. Create an [`IWICImagingFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690281.aspx) instance.
3. Create an [`IWICBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719675.aspx) instance from the `HBITMAP` ([`IWICImagingFactory::CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690287.aspx)).
4. Create an [`IWICStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719782.aspx) instance ([`IWICImagingFactory::CreateStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690325.aspx)), and attach it to a filename ([`IWICStream::InitializeFromFilename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719788.aspx)).
5. Create an [`IWICBitmapEncoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690110.aspx) instance ([`IWICImagingFactory::CreateEncoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690311.aspx)), and associate it with the stream ([`IWICBitmapEncoder::Initialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690123.aspx)).
6. Create an [`IWICBitmapFrameEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690141.aspx) instance ([`IWICBitmapEncoder::CreateNewFrame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690116.aspx)), and initialize it in compliance with the source `HBITMAP` ([`IWICBitmapFrameEncode::Initialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690146.aspx), [`IWICBitmapFrameEncode::SetSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690154.aspx), [`IWICBitmapFrameEncode::SetPixelFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690151.aspx)).
7. Write bitmap data to the frame ([`IWICBitmapFrameEncode::WriteSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690159.aspx)).
8. Commit frame and data to stream ([`IWICBitmapFrameEncode::Commit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690142.aspx), [`IWICBitmapEncoder::Commit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690114.aspx)).

Translated to code:

```
#define COBJMACROS

#include <Objbase.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winerror.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Windowscodecs.lib")

HRESULT WriteBitmap(HBITMAP bitmap, const wchar_t* pathname) {

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // (1) Retrieve properties from the source HBITMAP.
    BITMAP bm_info = { 0 };
    if (!GetObject(bitmap, sizeof(bm_info), &bm_info))
        hr = E_FAIL;

    // (2) Create an IWICImagingFactory instance.
    IWICImagingFactory* factory = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                              &IID_IWICImagingFactory, &factory);

    // (3) Create an IWICBitmap instance from the HBITMAP.
    IWICBitmap* wic_bitmap = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = IWICImagingFactory_CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(factory, bitmap, NULL,
                                                        WICBitmapIgnoreAlpha,
                                                        &wic_bitmap);

    // (4) Create an IWICStream instance, and attach it to a filename.
    IWICStream* stream = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = IWICImagingFactory_CreateStream(factory, &stream);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = IWICStream_InitializeFromFilename(stream, pathname, GENERIC_WRITE);

    // (5) Create an IWICBitmapEncoder instance, and associate it with the stream.
    IWICBitmapEncoder* encoder = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = IWICImagingFactory_CreateEncoder(factory, &GUID_ContainerFormatBmp, NULL,
                                              &encoder);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = IWICBitmapEncoder_Initialize(encoder, (IStream*)stream,
                                          WICBitmapEncoderNoCache);

    // (6) Create an IWICBitmapFrameEncode instance, and initialize it
    // in compliance with the source HBITMAP.
    IWICBitmapFrameEncode* frame = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = IWICBitmapEncoder_CreateNewFrame(encoder, &frame, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = IWICBitmapFrameEncode_Initialize(frame, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = IWICBitmapFrameEncode_SetSize(frame, bm_info.bmWidth, bm_info.bmHeight);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        GUID pixel_format = GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppBGR;
        hr = IWICBitmapFrameEncode_SetPixelFormat(frame, &pixel_format);
    }

    // (7) Write bitmap data to the frame.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = IWICBitmapFrameEncode_WriteSource(frame, (IWICBitmapSource*)wic_bitmap,
                                               NULL);

    // (8) Commit frame and data to stream.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = IWICBitmapFrameEncode_Commit(frame);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = IWICBitmapEncoder_Commit(encoder);

    // Cleanup
    if (frame)
        IWICBitmapFrameEncode_Release(frame);
    if (encoder)
        IWICBitmapEncoder_Release(encoder);
    if (stream)
        IWICStream_Release(stream);
    if (wic_bitmap)
        IWICBitmap_Release(wic_bitmap);
    if (factory)
        IWICImagingFactory_Release(factory);

    return hr;
}
```

Here's a companion test application to showcase the usage. Make sure to `#define OEMRESOURCE` prior to including any system headers to allow use of the `OBM_` images.

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t** argv) {

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return -1;

    HBITMAP bitmap = LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(OBM_ZOOM), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
                               LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);

    hr = WriteBitmap(bitmap, argv[1]);

    // Cleanup
    if (bitmap)
        DeleteObject(bitmap);

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

This will load a system-provided bitmap, and save it to the pathname specified as an argument on the command line.

## Limitations:

- No support for alpha channels. Although bitmaps version 5 support alpha channels, I am not aware of any way to find out, whether an `HBITMAP` refers to a bitmap with an alpha channel, nor would I know, how to determine, whether it is pre-multiplied. If you do want to support an alpha channel, make sure to set the `EnableV5Header32bppBGRA` property to `VARIANT_TRUE` (see [BMP Format: Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430020.aspx#encoding)).
- No support for palletized bitmaps (bpp <= 8). If you are dealing with palletized bitmaps, make sure to supply an appropriate `HPALETTE` in the call to `IWICImagingFactory::CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP`.
- The encoder is initialized with the `GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppBGR` pixel format constant. A more versatile implementation would deduce a compatible pixel format from the source `HBITMAP`.

Comment: To support alpha channel (when supported by Windows), use  WICBitmapUseAlpha in CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP, get an IPropertyBag2 in CreateNewFrame, write 'EnableV5Header32bppBGRA' to VARIANT_TRUE to it, and pass this bag to frame's Initialize (don't check errors to keep working on old Windows). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/bmp-format-overview#enablev5header32bppbgra